# use knockout js observable value as variable

Tags: c#, knockout.js

I have the following:

```
<span data-bind="text: total"></span>
```

from knockout js, how can I pass this value to code behind ?

Comment: you cannot ... if you want to pass this to the server you either have to use this inside a  `<form>` (in some valid field) and submit - or you have to make something like an AJAX call (in knockout probably using jquery/`post`,`get`, `ajax`) and pass it from there ... is this webforms or mvc?

Comment: ok, could I store as a session variable ?

Comment: same thing - session variables are on the server (between requests) - knockout, bindings, etc. is happening on the client (long) after the server rendered the html ... *WinForms* right? ... look this is just my opinion but a honest advice: drop this and do MVC - you'll never get a feeling for web-development using winforms - it gives you a totaly bogus mind-model of what is going on

Comment: what you could do is putting this into cookies (by observing your `total` observable in JS) on the client and looking at them on the server ... but this is just as bad as the stuff webforms is using to *simulate state*

Answer (score 0):

Carsten was accurate with the ajax call. You'll have an event, possibly from a button click, with a function that does something like,

```
//html

//... form that adds to total
<span data-bind="text: total"></span> 
<button data-bind="click: mySubmit">Submit Total</button>

//js controller
self.total = 0;

self.mySubmit = function(){
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: myBackendControllerUrl,
  data: self.total,
  success: function(){console.log("success!");},
  dataType: JSON
 });
}
```

Knockout is a clientside framework. To get your data from the client, to the server, you'll need something like the above. You'll need to create a controller on your server side that can receive this. I hope this helps get you started.